# Remove object from list after lifetime expires

Tags: python, oop

I am creating a program that spawns objects randomly.  These objects have a limited lifetime.

I create these objects and place them in a list.  The objects keep track of how long they exist and eventually expire.  They are no longer needed after expiration.

I would like to delete the objects after they expire but I'm not sure how to reference the specific object in the list to delete it.

```
if something:

    list.append(SomeObject())
```

---- later---

I would like a cleanup process that looks at the variable in the Object and if it is expired, then remove it from the list.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you tell if an object has expired by inspection? Would something like `list = [obj for obj in list if not obj.expired]` work?

Comment: you want to use `weakref`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html. you might need to use an additional weakkey/value dictionary, but this should work.

Comment: jonrsharpe - thanks, that solution worked for me.

Comment: Object's deleting themselves from lists or other containers they might be in is a poor design. jonsharpe's comment showing how something else external might update the list is a better approach IMHO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The only problem I see with doing that is if an object has indeed been deleted, then the `if not obj.expired` clause will be attempting to access something that no longer exists.

Comment: @martineau what do you mean by "been deleted"? Even if you have another reference `obj = Obj()` and `l.append(obj)`, `del obj` *won't* affect `l`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The OP's code does a `list.append(SomeObject())` so the only reference to the object is from the list (not counting the `obj` in the list comprehension statement).

Comment: @martineau and if it's deleted from the list `del l[i]` it won't be iterated over in the list comprehension. I still don't see how you could end up trying to call `.expired` on a deleted object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Hmmm, if the object was deleted from the list with a `del l[i]` then there would be no need to update the list with the comprehension. Perhaps "expired" and "deleted" aren't the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the refCount in case you define "no longer used" as "no other object keeps a reference". Which is a good way, for as no references exist, the object can no longer be accessed and may be disposed of. In fact, Python's garbage collector will do that for you.

Where it goes wrong is when you also have all the instances in a list. That also counts as a refeference to the object and it therefore never will be disposed of.

For example, a list of state variables that are not only referenced by their owning objects, but also by a list to allow linear access. Explicitly call a cleanup function from the accessor to keep the list clean:

```
GlobalStateList = []
def gcOnGlobalStateList():
  for s in reversed(GlobalStateList):
    if (getrefcount(s) <= 3): # 1=GlobalStateList, 2=Iterator, 3=getrefcount()
      GlobalStateList.remove(s)

def getGlobalStateList():
  gcOnGlobalStateList()
  return GlobalStateList
```

Note that even looking at the refcount increases it, so the test-value is three or less.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your concept of `SomeObject` "expiry" is not directly related to the underlying Python object lifetime (reference counting, etc.) I would suggest that the easiest way to purge the list is to occasionally run through it, dereferencing any `expired` objects:

```
lst = [obj for obj in lst if not obj.expired]
```

Note that you shouldn't call your own variables `list`, as this will shadow the built-in.